# How to create database, schema, and then table inside Postgresql using init.sql

Tags: postgresql, docker, ddl, init

I am trying to create an init.sql file to automatically create an user, database, schema, and table. Currently, the user and database are created, but I am having troubles with my schema and table.  Please see below for my code:

docker-compose:

```
postgres_db:
image: postgres:14.1
restart: unless-stopped
environment:
  POSTGRES_USER: ${SERVER_DB_USER}
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${SERVER_DB_PASS}
volumes:
  - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  - ./admin/config:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
networks:
  - bypass
```

init.sql file inside /admin/config:

```
CREATE USER bypass;
CREATE DATABASE bypass;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE bypass TO bypass;

\c bypass;
CREATE SCHEMA bypass_project;

CREATE TABLE bypass_project.Bypass_Data (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    Date_Time TIMESTAMP,
    Module VARCHAR(25),
    Area VARCHAR(25),
                         );
```

After running docker-compose up, I am not able to see the schema and the table.  I'm pretty sure `\c bypass` is used incorrectly.  How do I connect to the bypass database and create everything there?

Comment: Are you sure that you want do it here? Usually it's being done at application level with some migrations mechanism.

Comment: I am definitely new to database management.  I am making an application that will continuously write data from Python to Postgresql.  I assumed that the database structure had to be constructed before data can flow into it.  What would be the best practices to put in init.sql files and where would I populate other items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definitely have errors in your SQL syntax in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. You should remove trailing comma:

```
CREATE TABLE bypass_project.Bypass_Data (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    Date_Time TIMESTAMP,
    Module VARCHAR(25),
    Area VARCHAR(25)
);
```

Also you can try (second `bypass` is your DB user):

```
\c bypass bypass;
```

instead of

```
\c bypass;
```

Also `\c` is a command specific to psql. If you try to execute an SQL script containing such command in another client, it will not work.

In this case you can try to use `init.sh` script instead of `init.sql` and use `psql` in your bash-script. You can see full example [here](https://graspingtech.com/docker-compose-postgresql/).

If it does not help you, could you provide more information? I think docker-compose log would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should leave just this in your `init.sql`:

```sql
CREATE USER bypass;
CREATE DATABASE bypass;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE bypass TO bypass;
```

Then you should expose the DB port and connect to it from your application container. If you are using Python, as you mentioned in comment, you should use some DB migrations mechanism, like Django ORM or SQLAlchemy. On deployment of python application migration mechanism should be called, it would actualise the state of your database.

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/) is an example of configuration of Django + PostgreSQL setup and here is a [guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/) about Django migrations.